# password MAXDAYS not working with solaris 11.3

Tags: password, solaris

I am enforcing password complexity rules for solaris 11.3 and solaris 11.4

Changed file

```
/etc/default/passwd
```

change these parameters in above file

```
MAXDAYS=60
MINDAYS=1
WARNDAYS=7
HISTORY=3
MINDIFF=1
MINUPPER=1
MINLOWER=1
MINSPECIAL=1
```

These changes are working fine for solaris 11.4 but not for solaris 11.3

Need ideas how to setup these rules for solaris 11.3 as well

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Changing the values in `/etc/default/passwd` won't change the expiration date of already-existing accounts.  It changes the *default* value used when the account is *created*.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Its not working for newly created user.  Instead it works fine if set MAXWEEK=